# Open all <a> links on page that do not have string match in new tab with jquery

Tags: javascript

I need a script that will open up all the href links in new tabs that do NOT contain the query I've specified in the indexOf. This loop does basically exactly the opposite of what I need it to do. I just can't work out how to reverse it's function. Maybe it's right in front of my face and I'm just not seeing it.

So, I am working with this right now.

```
(function(){
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    var href = links[i].href;
    if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('facebook.com/search') !=-1){
      window.open(links[i].href);
    }
  }
})();
```

I've tried placing `!` and `!=` in this script but it's not working and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns -1 when it does not find the specified substring in the string. Right now, you're opening links that have that substring. Your if statement should look like:

```
if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('facebook.com/search') == -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem I have is that when I do it this way, it seems to never stop opening (ie the loop never ends). Which is weird to me because I feel like it should but maybe I'm again missing something.

Comment: Depends on how many links you have on the page, but it may just seem like it's infinite